# Using multiple z-indexes on a single page

Tags: css, z-index

This will be very hard to explain, so I will simply show my jsFiddle attempt. I would like the orange container to be in the very back of everything on the page. I would then like the banner to be on top of the orange container, but behind the two white div containers.

You can view my attempt [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wq8YG/2/)

Thanks for any help!

Evan

Comment: Are you sure you linked that properly?

Answer (score 1):

not sure entirely what you mean. the order and what is inside what, makes a huge difference so only showing us two of the divs inst helpful. but is this what you mean?

```
<div class'mainContainer'>
     <div class=orange'></div>
     <div class='banner'></div>
     <div class='div1'></div>
     <div class='div2'></div>
</div>
```

with that order you wouldn't need z-index. in html an element is on top of its parents and previous siblings. we use z-index when we want to change this.

if your structure is different pls post it.

in reply to your first comment
same principle applies. the latter elements are on top of the previous ones. so for them to be bottom to top: orange, banner, and two divs. then just add them in that order. Also I didn't point out before z-index with a negative value don't allow the user to interact with the element. i.e they will not be able to select or click anything inside whatever has a negative z-index.
generally for info on html/css you should check w3cschools. heres a link about z-index
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_CDLBTJD4M&feature=player_embedded as another person posted in order for z-index to work it needs to be `position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed;`

Comment: Yeah, that is a different format. I have a main container, as you do. The 'maincontainer' will be orange (for example purposes). I want the page-wide banner to be completely in front of the 'maincontainer' I then want the two div containers to be above the banner.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need z-indices at all to do this. Your problem is coming from the fact that your white divs are statically positioned.

I have removed the `z-index` styles and added `position:relative` to the white divs:

http://jsfiddle.net/Wq8YG/4/

Is that what you were trying to achieve?